# Propositional fusions?

Tags: morphology

I was wondering if there are any examples from natural or constructed languages that offer a syntactic form equating to a sentence like “I used to live in Japan and my mom is from Japan”.

The above connects two propositions but it doesn’t fuse their form. However, many other aspects of language are compositional - “went” means (apparently) both “go” and “past tense” at the same time.

It would be cool to know about a sentence which has the form of a single proposition yet can be effectively parsed to contain two distinct propositions - some way of delivering multiple propositions at the same time. (I am open to really experimental stuff.)

Comment: You can make up examples in English where a single proposition can be parsed to contain two distinct propositions (e.g., “My brother and I love and hate shellfish” can be parsed as proposing ‘my brother loves shellfish’ and ‘I hate shellfish’). You could simplify your example to “I used to live in and my mother is from Japan” to achieve a similar effect. But I doubt there are any languages that could present “My nan’s curries are spicy, and Kelce scored a home run” as a single proposition.

Comment: How about "I like apples and hate bananas"? Pretty clearly two separate propositions there—one subject, two predicates.